# WordPunctTokenizer and sklearn GridSearchCV PicklingError when n_jobs=-1

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying scikit-learn `gridsearchcv` on a problem and it errors out with a `PicklingError` when `n_jobs=-1` is set in sklearn's GridSearchCV method. I've searched forums for a solution but couldn't find much that was helpful. It appears the error is in the multiprocessing module and not been able to serialize the objects in a parallel processing environment. I'm not using any custom classes here, just the standard sklearn transformers and estimators. Any help to solve this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer

X = np.asarray(['This is a sample text',
                'Here is another one',
                'How about this?',
                'Some random text again',
                'Need to make this work',
                'sklearn is awesome!',
                'Adding more train data',
                'and more and more data'           
               ])

y = np.asarray([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1])

pipeline = Pipeline([
               ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), tokenizer=WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize, stop_words='english')),
               ('estimator', LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced'))
           ])

param_grid = dict()
param_grid['vectorizer__sublinear_tf'] = [True, False]
param_grid['vectorizer__smooth_idf'] = [True, False]
param_grid['vectorizer__norm'] = ['l1', 'l2']
param_grid['estimator__penalty'] = ['l1', 'l2']

grid_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1_micro')
grid_clf.fit(X, y)

print "\nBest parameters:", grid_clf.best_params_
print "Best score:", grid_clf.best_score_, "\n"
```

**Error**:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 16 candidates, totalling 48 fits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-04b1aa29a4ee> in <module>()
     30 
     31 grid_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1_micro')
---> 32 grid_clf.fit(X, y)
     33 
     34 print "\nBest parameters:", grid_clf.best_params_
....

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod
```

Comment: i think I know how to solve this but can you add the full code and data so that i can verify ? also, are you using Windows ?

Comment: Thanks sera. Appreciate the help. I updated the code to include a fully functional example. Couldn't share the real data, so added some dummy data. 

I think I figured out what was wrong, but not able to explain it really. If you remove the parameter `tokenizer=WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize` from the TfidfVectorizer, the code actually runs without an error.

Btw, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: yes i can reproduce the error on my mac. the tokenizer=WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize produces the error. There is a problem when using it and using multiprocessing at the same time. I am looking for a solution

Comment: Thank much. I'll keep working on it and update here if I find a solution.

Comment: okay. me too. however it seems that we need to open a pull request in github maybe